# Finding `n1` TRUEs wrapped in between two `n2` FALSEs, the whole thing wrapped in between `n3` TRUEs, etc

Tags: r, search, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

From a sequence of TRUEs and falses, I wanted to make a function that returns TRUE whether there is a series of at least `n1` TRUEs somewhere in the sequence. Here is that function:

```
fun_1 = function(TFvec, n1){
    nbT = 0
    solution = -1
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
            if (x[i]){
            nbT = nbT + 1
               if (nbT == n1){
                return(T)
                break
               }
            } else {
                nbT = 0
            }
        }
        return (F) 
}
```

Test:

```
x = c(T,F,T,T,F,F,T,T,T,F,F,T,F,F)
fun_1(x,3) # TRUE
fun_1(x,4) # FALSE
```

Then, I needed a function that returns TRUE if in a given list boolean vector, there is a series of at least `n1` TRUEs wrapped by at least two series (one on each side) of `n2` falses. Here the function:

```
fun_2 = function(TFvec, n1, n2){
    if (n2 == 0){
        fun_1(TFvec, n2)        
    }
    nbFB = 0
    nbFA = 0
    nbT = 0
    solution = -1
    last = F
    for (i in 1:length(TFvec)){
        if(TFvec[i]){           
            nbT = nbT + 1
            if (nbT == n1 & nbFB >= n2){
                solution = i-n1+1
            }
            last = T
        } else {
            if (last){
                nbFB = 0
                nbFA = 0        
            }
            nbFB = nbFB + 1
            nbFA = nbFA + 1
            nbT = 0
            if (nbFA == n2 & solution!=-1){
                return(T)
            }
            last = F
        }
    }
    return(F)
}
```

It is maybe not a very efficient function though! And I haven't tested it 100 times but it looks like it works fine!

Test:

```
x = c(T,F,T,T,F,F,T,T,T,F,F,T,F,F)
fun_2(x, 3, 2) # TRUE
fun_2(x, 3, 3) # FALSE
```

Now, believe it or not, I'd like to make a function (`fun_3`) that returns TRUE if in the boolean vector there is a (at least) series of at least `n1` TRUEs wrapped in between (at least) two (one on each side) series of `n2` falses where the whole thing (the three series) are wrapped in between (at least) two (one on each side) series of `n3` TRUEs. And as I am afraid to have to bring this problem even further, I am asking here for help to create a function `fun_n` in which we enter two arguments `TFvec` and `list_n` where `list_n` is a list of `n` of any length.

**Can you help me to create the function `fun_n`?**

Comment: Cannot `rle` function be useful in your case?

Comment: `trueseq <- function(x,n) {r <- rle(x); any(r$lengths[r$values] >= n)}` might be a re-conceptualisation of your first function using `rle`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For convenience, record the length of the number of thresholds

```
n = length(list_n)
```

Represent the vector of TRUE and FALSE as a run-length encoding, remembering the length of each run for convenience

```
r = rle(TFvec); l = r$length
```

Find possible starting locations

```
idx = which(l >= list_n[1] & r$value)
```

Make sure the starting locations are embedded enough to satisfy all tests

```
idx = idx[idx > n - 1 & idx + n - 1 <= length(l)]
```

Then check that lengths of successively remote runs are consistent with the condition, keeping only those starting points that are

```
for (i in seq_len(n - 1)) {
    if (length(idx) == 0)
        break     # no solution
    thresh = list_n[i + 1]
    test = (l[idx + i] >= thresh) & (l[idx - i] >= thresh)
    idx = idx[test]
}
```

If there are any values left in `idx`, then these are the indexes into the rle satisfying the condition; the starting point(s) in the initial vector are `cumsum(l)[idx - 1] + 1`.

Combined:

```
runfun = function(TFvec, list_n) {
    ## setup
    n = length(list_n)
    r = rle(TFvec); l = r$length

    ## initial condition
    idx = which(l >= list_n[1] & r$value)
    idx = idx[idx > n - 1 & idx + n - 1 <= length(l)]

    ## adjacent conditions
    for (i in seq_len(n - 1)) {
        if (length(idx) == 0)
            break     # no solution
        thresh = list_n[i + 1]
        test = (l[idx + i] >= thresh) & (l[idx - i] >= thresh)
        idx = idx[test]
    }

    ## starts = cumsum(l)[idx - 1] + 1
    ## any luck?
    length(idx) != 0
}
```

This is fast and allows for runs >= the threshold, as stipulated in the question; for example

```
x = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1000000, TRUE)
system.time(runfun(x, rep(2, 5)))
```

completes in less than 1/5th of a second.

A fun generalization allows for flexible condition, e.g., runs of exactly `list_n`, as in the rollapply solution

```
runfun = function(TFvec, list_n, cond=`>=`) {
    ## setup
    n = length(list_n)
    r = rle(TFvec); l = r$length

    ## initial condition
    idx = which(cond(l, list_n[1]) & r$value)
    idx = idx[idx > n - 1 & idx + n - 1 <= length(l)]

    ## adjacent conditions
    for (i in seq_len(n - 1)) {
        if (length(idx) == 0)
            break     # no solution
        thresh = list_n[i + 1]
        test = cond(l[idx + i], thresh) & cond(l[idx - i], thresh)
        idx = idx[test]
    }

    ## starts = cumsum(l)[idx - 1] + 1
    ## any luck?
    length(idx) != 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The solution looks really great and I very much how fast it computes. I don't totally understand it for the moment I have to study it a bit more. I am surprised that the following returns FALSE: `x = c(F,T,F); runfun(x, list(1,1))` Do I misunderstand how the function works or is there a mistake somewhere? There is a series of 1 TRUE wrapped between two (one on each side) of 1 FALSE.

Comment: I used the debugger `debug(runfun)`, invoked your test case `runfun(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), c(1, 1))`, using the command 'n' to step through lines, checking each. I found the right start `idx` 2 to start, but then `idx > n & idx + n <= length(l)` eliminated my choice, because 2 is not greater than 2; the condition is wrong and I've updated the response

Comment: Nice! I appreciate you also took the time to teach me about the `debug` function. Great answer +1

Answer (score 4):

Create a template, `tpl` of zeros and ones, convert it to a regex pattern `pat`.  Convert `x` to a single string of zeros and ones and use `grepl` to match `pat` to it.  No packages are used.

```
fun_n <- function(x, lens) {
  n <- length(lens)
  reps <- c(rev(lens), lens[-1])
  TF <- if (n == 1) 1 else if (n %% 2) 1:0 else 0:1
  tpl <- paste0(rep(TF, length = n), "{", reps, ",}")
  pat <- paste(tpl, collapse = "")
  grepl(pat, paste(x + 0, collapse = ""))
}

# test
x <- c(F, T, T, F, F, T, T, T, F, F, T, T, T, F)
fun_n(x, 3:1)
## TRUE
fun_n(x, 1:3)
## FALSE
fun_n(x, 100)
## FALSE
fun_n(x, 3)
## TRUE
fun_n(c(F, T, F), c(1, 1))
## [1] TRUE
fun_n(c(F, T, T, F), c(1, 1)) 
## [1] TRUE
```

Run time is not as fast as `runfun` on the example below but still quite fast running 10,000 instances of the example shown in slightly over 2 seconds on my laptop.  Also the code is relatively short in length and loop-free.

```
> library(rbenchmark)
> benchmark(runfun(x, 1:3), fun_n(x, 1:3), replications = 10000)[1:4]

            test replications elapsed relative
2  fun_n(x, 1:3)        10000    2.29    1.205
1 runfun(x, 1:3)        10000    1.90    1.000
```

Comment: added additional solution which is equally short but quite a bit faster

Comment: The requirement is 'at least' n, so `fun_n(c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), c(1, 1))` should return TRUE.